# How to get a count of specific process using ps command and then sort nd count it user wise

Tags: linux, processes

I need to see the count of specific process userwise. For example I do

```
ps -ef | grep apache
```

this lists all apache processes. Now I want a count of how many processes each user is running in Linux.

how can I get this.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. But I need to see the count of only the users that are running specific command say apache. all your replies are giving me the count for all the users running different commands. I only need the count of users running specific command like apache

Answer (score 1):

One solution:

```
gohu@Luna:~$ ps -ef | grep -v '^UID' | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -rg
    151 gohu
    149 root
      2 nobody
      2 avahi
      1 syslog
      1 rtkit
      1 ntp
      1 message+
      1 daemon
      1 colord
```

---

With:

- `ps -ef`: list processes, with user as first element of line
- `grep -v '^UID'` : remove header line
- `awk '{print $1}'` : grab first element of line (the user)
- `sort`: we need to sort before running `uniq -c`
- `uniq -c`: merge duplicate lines and count occurrences
- `sort -rg`: numerical sort, most occurrences first

Answer (score 1):

Short solution:

```
ps -eo "%U" --sort=user h | uniq -c
```

---

- `--sort=user` - sort by `user name`
- `uniq -c` - count number of processes for each unique user

Answer (score 0):

try

```
ps -e -o user h| awk '{u[$1]++} END { for (user in u ) printf "%s:%d\n",user,u[user]}'
```

where

- `-e` list all process
- `-o user` only output user
- `h` do not display header
- awk will count user, and display count at end of ps's output.

EDIT: can be (sort of) shorterned to, thank to @Gohu.

```
ps -e -o user h| sort | uniq -c | sort -rg
```

Comment: To get it more shortened: replace `sort  | uniq -c `  by `sort -u` (for unique). Maybe you can combine to `sort -urg`, don't know by now ;)

Comment: Whops, no! `-c` from `uniq` is missing, new attempt: `sort -urg | nl` :D

Comment: `sort -u ` will loose count of the number of process.

Comment: OK, I see, you are counting inside awk array (`u[$1]++`). Now I understand, nice solution! Forget about my comments before, but I won't delete in the case of someone else would do like me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

POSIXly:

```
ps -Ao user= | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn
```